# Let $X_1,X_2\sim N(0,1)$. How to find joint pdf of $\,Y_1=X_1^2+X_2^2\,$ and$\,\,Y_2=X_1/\sqrt{Y_1}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2\sim N(0,1)$. How to find joint pdf of $\,Y_1=X_1^2+X_2^2\,$ and$\,\,Y_2=\frac{\displaystyle X_1}{\displaystyle \sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}}$?

I have tried to use Jacobian matrix to do transformation, but it is not one-to-one function... Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Are the $X_k$ independent?

Comment: Do you really  mean to say that $X_1^2$ has normal distribution?  If it is the $X_i$ that are (independent) standard normal, look at the geometry (polar coordinates) and things should be clear.

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: Hint: can you show $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent?